# ubuntu core specifically for pi 3 B+

Tags: ubuntu-core

Please can someone build a working image for Raspberry pi 3 B+ ?

There are many answers dismissing this saying use the `ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz`

This doesn't work for pi 3 B+ (the current version and the one people can buy and probably want to use).

Thanks and again please don't dismiss this as a duplicate as the others asking the same were; the pi 3 B+ doesn't work with the current or nightly build of `ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz` (I've tried both and neither work, tested with multiple SD cards and multiple power supplies to reduce a single cause or issue apart from the image).

with `ubuntu-core-16-armhf+raspi3.img.xy` I get no HDMI, and the red LED flashes in sequence 4 slow / slow fast (I think, it's not obvious)

with `ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xy` I get rainbow screen, solid red led and nothing else.

The same SD cards have been used and worked with rasbian and other distributions; I'd really like to deploy some pi 3 B+'s for a project but cannot start if there is no supported or working core for it.

Comment: Have you filed a bug for this yet?